# Distinct Group By using mongodb with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, group-by, pymongo

I have a collection of entries like this :

```
db.mesh_captors.save({'arduino': 0xCB, 'pin': 14, 'value': 35, 'date': datetime.utcnow()})
db.mesh_captors.save({'arduino': 0xCB, 'pin': 14, 'value': 63, 'date': datetime.utcnow()})
db.mesh_captors.save({'arduino': 0xCB, 'pin': 15, 'value': 126, 'date': datetime.utcnow()})
db.mesh_captors.save({'arduino': 0x7B, 'pin': 14, 'value': 121, 'date': datetime.utcnow()})
```

I want to get the last value of each pin of an arduino. With MySQL, I would have wrote this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT pin, value
FROM mesh_captors
WHERE arduino = 203
GROUP_BY pin
ORDER BY date DESC
```

But using MongoDB, I am not quite sure of how to do so.

I tried something like this but is it good enough ?

```
reducer = Code("""
              function (doc, out) {
                  if(out.date == 0 || out.date < doc.date) {
                       out.date = doc.date;
                       out.value = doc.value;
                  }
              }
              """)

captors_value = db.mesh_captors.group(key=['pin'], condition={'arduino': int(arduino_id)}, reduce=reducer, initial={'date': 0})
```

By now, I takes more than 4.5s to execute the request and it takes more and more time as the number of entries grows.

Comment: You have asked a question then marked a part as ANSWER then EDIT and asked another question. Pretty confusing ? Please simplify

Comment: Ok, I did re-factor my question

Comment: have you defined an index on `pin` , `arduino`

Comment: I did that : `db.mesh_captors.ensure_index([('pin', ASCENDING), ('date', DESCENDING)])` should I add one on arduino ?

Comment: yes, try it. will give an alternative, give it a shot.

Comment: this can be done using the new aggregation framework. you want the latest value, right? not the largest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use version 2.1 which is the development version of upcoming 2.2 release, then you can use the new [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/#aggregation-framework) to do this query much faster than you could with map/reduce.

Here is what the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-pipeline) would look like to get the value that's the latest date for that arguino and pin:

```
[{$match:{arduino: 0xCB}},
{$project:
       {_id: 0, arduino:1, pin:1, maxVal: {date:1, val:"$value"} }
},
{$group:
       {_id:{"arduino":1, "pin":1},maxDate:{$max:"$maxVal"} }    
},
{$project:
       {_id:0, "arduino":"$_id.arduino" , "pin":"$_id.pin","date":"$maxDate.date",value:"$maxDate.val"}
}]
```

If run on your sample data, the result is:

```
> db.mesh_captors.aggregate(agg)
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "arduino" : 203,
            "pin" : 15,
            "date" : "Sat Jun 09 2012 16:22:50 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
            "value" : 126
        },
        {
            "arduino" : 203,
            "pin" : 14,
            "date" : "Sat Jun 09 2012 16:23:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
            "value" : 63
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You can access aggregation framework from Python via pymongo support for `db.runCommand`.  You would execute `db.runCommand` passing it the document

```
{"aggregate":"mesh_captors", "pipeline":<pipeline-goes-here>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use group in sharded collections and that makes it bad choice for most of the tasks. If your not using sharded collections that might be close to the best performance u can get. (Correct me if I'm wrong) You should try implementing the same task with MapReduce and aggregate and compare performance.

[This article](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/06/using-mongodbs-new-aggregation.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20JustALittlePython%20%28Just%20a%20little%20Python%29) should help you better understand some advanced aggregation from mongodb.

Comment: I am not using sharding, but I think, I must implement some cron job, that will delete old data so I will keep having 11ms of speed.